# Regular expression that matches any string parenthesized n times

Tags: regex

For example, it should match `(aaa)`, `((aaa))`, `(((aaa)))`, but not `((aaa)` or `(aaa))`.
Is it even possible?

P.S. If it matters, I need this regular expression for JavaScript.

Comment: Quotes are easy, parenthesis are hard...

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, could you please tell how would you write such regex with quotes instead of parenthesis?

Comment: With quotes it would look like this: `("+)[^"]+\1`.  We put the first set of quotes in a matching group, and then we say `\1` to reference that group.  So if `("+)` matches 13 quotes, `\1` has to match the same.  Depending on the input you may want to put something before or after the pattern, such as `\b` or `\s` to stop it from skipping quotes at the start of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to do a little more than regex (and I mean just a little), you can use this function.

```
check_parens('(((aaa)))');
check_parens('((aaa)))');
check_parens('aaa');


function check_parens(hay) {
    var re = /(\(+)(?:[^)]+)(\)+)/g;
    var matches = re.exec(hay);

    if (matches === null || matches[1].length !== matches[2].length)
        alert("Too bad...");
    else 
        alert("We're good!");
}
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/85bxJ/1/)

Comment: I added some more error checking to cover the case of not matching at all.

Answer (score 1):

The language you are describing is [context free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) and not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), thus there is no such regular expression. One can easily show a [homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_homomorphism#String_homomorphism) to `L={a^n * b^n}` for this language, and `L` is a well known irregular language.

It might be possible with some regex expansions, but not in standard regular expression, which originally standed for regular languages.